# Kafka permission on a topic creating a Group Authorization Exception

Tags: apache-kafka, acl, kafka-topic, access-control-list

So I have a Kafka cluster running with zookeeper with SSL. I gave a read permission to a user for a specific topic on the Kafka ACL: I can see it in zookeeper.
When this user is consuming the data, they are getting a Group Authorization Exception.
Do I need to add every group to the ACL? I am confuse about this error.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can update your post with exception trace.

Keeping that aside, the following is the exception we receive, if any client is not Authorized to perform Produce/Consume events.

```
EXCEPTION="org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [<<TopicName>>]\n"; EXCEPTION_TYPE="org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: <<Topic>>\n"
```

If you are receiving such exception, you need to make sure you have defined your ACL principle correctly.

### Principle Definition

- Kafka acls are defined in the general format of "**Principal P is [Allowed/Denied] Operation O From Host H on any Resource R matching ResourcePattern RP**".

In order to add, remove or list ACLs you can use the Kafka authorizer CLI. By default, if no ResourcePatterns match a specific Resource R, then R has no associated acls, and therefore no one other than super users is allowed to access R. If you want to change that behaviour, you can include the following in server.properties.

### Sample Principle

- Suppose you want to add an ACL "Principals User:Bob and User:Alice are allowed to perform Operation Read and Write on Topic Test-Topic from IP 198.51.100.0 and IP 198.51.100.1". You can do that by executing the CLI with following options:

  bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:Bob --allow-principal User:Alice --allow-host 198.51.100.0 --allow-host 198.51.100.1 --operation Read --operation Write --topic Test-topic

Comment: I authorize the topic but I am getting an exception on the Group not being authorized